# On Win 10, I've installed emacs (with AucTeX) and Miktex. How do I get emacs to invoke MikTex?

Tags: miktex, windows, emacs

I've installed emacs and installed the AucTeX package using emacs (which seems to be the consensus advice). I've installed MikTeX. How do I get C-c C-c latex to invoke MikTex and let me view the compiled file?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you able to run the MikTeX tools (pdflatex etc.) from the command-line? If it is found there, what is the error message in Emacs?

Comment: I don't think the problem is with MikTeX. If I launch TeXworks from the MikTeX console, MikTeX runs fine. When I try to run MikTeX from emacs, I get the following in the *tex-shell* buffer: `code`c:\Users\Owner\Documents\AA\Statement>pdflatex "\nonstopmode\input" "notes.tex"
pdflatex "\nonstopmode\input" "notes.tex"
'pdflatex' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

c:\Users\Owner\Documents\AA\Statement>latex "\nonstopmode\input" "notes.tex"
latex "\nonstopmode\input" "notes.tex"
'latex' is not recognized as an internal or ... `code`

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. I installed emacs and then MikTeX. After installing MikTeX, I needed to reboot so that emacs recognized the command `pdflatex`.